AC-DC power rating
I am using the LRS350 AC-DC power module. The specs are as shown below -

The rated power is 350 W and the max current allowed is approx 14.6 A. Assuming an efficiency of 88 %, the input power should be approx - 398 W. This is the power drawn from the AC socket.
The socket I have can give - 230 V, 5 A. Thus, the max power possible is 1250 W.
Now, what is this rating -

The input typical of 3.4 A at 230 V AC means a power of 782 W. How is this possible?

For one thing, this question quotes both inrush current & "AC", a distinction not made in the older one. am using so what is the input current reading on what type of instrument (&load)?

On page 2, note 9 in the datasheet you can read, that the device does not meet the harmonic current requirements of EN61000-2-3. It seams to have a very bad power factor. There is no PFC stage in the block diagram either.
This explains the high current value of 3.4 A (782 VA). You are not allowed to use it in many countries.
